# How to render XNA GraphicsDevice to Windows Forms Graphics object?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, xna

I use XNA in Windows Forms.
According to Microsoft tutorial, the control that uses XNA should have something like this in `OnPaint()`:

```
GraphicsDevice.Present(srcRectangle, null, this.Handle);
```

But I wanted to draw additional things with Windows Forms Graphics object. I can do it just fine placing drawing code after `GraphicsDevice.Present()`, but I get horrible flickering. That's why I thought of setting double buffering this way:

```
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

But unfortunately it will draw only thing drawn with Graphics object (or the internal controls). That's why I would like to render my XNA scene to Graphics object. Is there any way for that?

I have tried:

- Built-in WinForms double buffering, but not only each second frame is black but those normal frames are flickering too.
- Saving content of window after `Present()` and then showing it with Graphics object.
- Rendering to RenderTarget2D and then created bitmap to show on Graphics object with `Image.FromStream(Stream)` where stream came from `RenderTarget.SaveAsPng()`.

Every idea failed. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,
Rendering to Texture is OK. Just rembember to call:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

Before you access data from it